# Maximal distance between random variables in interval

Tags: random-variables, interval-arithmetic

Suppose there are two random variables $A, B$ constrained in the intervals $A \in [a_{min}, a_{max}]$ and $B \in [b_{min}, b_{max}]$.

$a_{min}, b_{min} \leq 0$ and $a_{max}, b_{max} \geq 0$.

I calculate the maximal possible distance between $A$ and $B$ like this:

$d = \max \{ b_{max} - a_{min} , a_{max} - b_{min} \}$

Is this correct, and can it be generalized to more than two random variables (with the same constraints).

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.

I think you should define exactly what do you mean by the generalization. But, if I have understood correctly, what you are looking for is

$max\{(A_{max}-B_{min}): A,B \in W and A\ne B\}$

where $W$ is the set of the random variables.